Error Verify Signature XML DGI UY always return false
I am working on validating the signature of an XML envelope in this case from Uruguay,
but due to the signature verification method it always returns false using .Net C#
The tests carried out with unsuccessful results, apply the following code that obtains the certificate and the signature within a cycle, considering that the xml has several signatures and a single certificate.xml used to validate
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;

public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string xmlFilePath = @"d:\Sob_219999830019_Ej_Mod_19072016.xml";//args[0];

           XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
           xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;   /*It was validated by both true and false*/
            xmlDoc.Load(xmlFilePath);
           SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
           XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
           XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
           nsmgr.AddNamespace("DGICFE", "http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy");

            XmlNode certificateNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//DGICFE:Caratula/DGICFE:X509Certificate", nsmgr);
            if (certificateNode != null)
            {
                string certificateBase64 = certificateNode.InnerText;
                byte[] certificateData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(certificateBase64);
                X509Certificate2 dcert2 = new X509Certificate2(certificateData); 

                foreach (XmlElement element in nodeList)
                {                   
                    signedXml.LoadXml(element);                   
                    signedXml.SigningKey = dcert2.GetRSAPublicKey();
                    /*in these 3 verifications it returns false*/
                    bool passes = signedXml.CheckSignature(dcert2, true);
                      passes = signedXml.CheckSignature(dcert2, false);
                    passes = signedXml.CheckSignature();
                    
                }
            }


        }

Checking the logs in the console I have this response, but it does not give any further indication that it may be failing
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 2 : [SignedXml#00245fb7, BeginCheckSignedInfo] Checking signature in SignedInfo with id. "(null)".
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 14 : [SignedXml#00245fb7, VerifySignedInfo] Checking SignedInfo using key RSACng#01475d71, 
signature description RSAPKCS1SHA1SignatureDescription,
 hash algorithm SHA1Cng and asymmetric signature deformatter RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter.

System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Verbose: 14 : [SignedXml#00245fb7, VerifySignedInfo] Actual hash value: 8247f7f76542509039de0f38150e4878250e51
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Verbose: 14 : [SignedXml#00245fb7, VerifySignedInfo] Raw signature: 91ef1705f3de4f83b310ae5e9f1089ea72b7ebb7d2f51171d34ed8cbe03c340cf5f9c3c87 
System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml Information: 12 : [SignedXml#00245fb7, VerificationFailure] Failed to verify SignedInfo.

Perform tests with different .net framework 3.0,3.5,4.0... up to 4.8 and .Net core 6 the result is the same.
I reviewed similar questions and none of the proposed solutions have worked for me.
The test xml is verified, that is, it has valid signatures... I attach a screenshot of the xml that I am verifying
Please can you help me by indicating what may be wrong in the code or what else I can verify?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You must validate that the certificate in the signature is the one you expect or otherwise ensure that you trust it. A XML file signed by a malicious user will come along with a malicious signature and your code will not detect that.

Hi @ixe013, I will take it into consideration
